# multiple Id arg django

Tags: django, url

I have an issue with my web-app django.

In example, user can add an artist, and with this artist, he can (list, delete, play) music. 
When the user click on the artist, the URL is 'music/1/' where the artist ID is 1, and music is listed.

When user want delete a music, the URL is 'delmusic/1/' where the music ID is 1.

delmusic function works, but returns an error PageNotFound with this http URL : 
'http://host.local/appli/delmusic/1/webgui.views.music'

My urls.py :

```
url(r'^music/(\d+)/$', 'webgui.views.music'),
url(r'^delmusic/(\d+)/$','webgui.views.delmusic'),
```

My music template :

```
<a href="{% url 'webgui.views.delmusic' music.id %}"style="margin-bottom: 3px" type="button">
```

My view :

```
def music(request, id):
listmusic = Music.objects.filter(artist=id)
return render(request, 'music.html', {'listmusic': listmusic})

def delmusic(request, id):
    music = Music.objects.get(id=id)
    music.delete()
    return redirect('webgui.views.music')
```

I think there is confusion with music.id and arist.id, but I don't know.. 
Maybe you will have an idea  ?

Comment: Note that it's a very bad idea to delete objects on a GET request. You should use a form with a POST for that.

Comment: Is it not too heavy ??  I have to admit that I don't see advantages just for Delete button, but if you think with a Form, my problem could be solved.. ?

Comment: @Isador, for example think for a moment that Google Spider is analyzing your site (with GET request) say bye to your data.

Comment: The system for my web-app (Raspberry Pi) don't need access to the Internet, just on a local network.  But I'm not sure to understand why 'say bye to your data'.    You are talking about Google Spider Crawling ? It could have my informations (or my files when add) with GET request ?

Comment: he means that google can hit your delete url and youll just end up with deleted items, unless you add authentication to your site (or at least the critical parts of it like edit/delete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a slight issue with your `urls.py` - the 2nd argument points to the views function, but is not used as a reference in the templates, for that you need to do:

```
url(r'^music/(\d+)/$', 'webgui.views.music', name='music'),
url(r'^delmusic/(\d+)/$','webgui.views.delmusic', name='delmusic'),
```

and then in the template

```
<a href="{% url 'delmusic' music.id %}" style="margin-bottom: 3px" type="button">
```

or if you had a namespace defined for your app in `django_settings/urls.py`:

```
<a href="{% url '<APPNAMESPACE>:delmusic' music.id %}" style="margin-bottom: 3px" type="button">
```

and then at then in `views.py` do

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def delmusic(request, id):
    music = Music.objects.get(id=id)
    artist_id = music.artist.id
    music.delete()
    return redirect(reverse('music', args=[artist_id]))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't works..  The same error : PageNotFound, django has tried the following Urls, etc..     The current URL, delmusic/1/webgui.views.music, didn't match any of these.

Comment: are you going directly to `delmusic/1/webgui.views.music` ? with the change in the template and urls.py, what is the button linking to now? make sure you refresh everything (a django restart might be needed for urls.py changes to take effect).

Comment: Now, the button displays 'host/app/delmusic/1' before I click on. But I don't understand why the URL adds at the end 'webgui.views.music' once I clicked...  Maybe because the delmusic function returns to 'webgui.views.music' without artist id ??  I tried with Apache and with Django (with restart) , but nothing..

Comment: it's because the redirect in your view function was pointing to the function name as well - edited my answer.

Comment: With the new method 'reverse', I've a new error : 'NoReverseMatch at /delmusic/4/'         `Exception Value: Reverse for 'music' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] `

Comment: yea you dont have a 'music' url defined without an argument in your urls.py - need to figure out where you want to redirect first. And don't forget to do some debugging of your own first - people here are happy to help, but it's welcome to see when the OP is trying himself too.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  'where you want to redirect first'.  Yes, I think it is maybe unclear. In fact, on /artist/ URL (page), I have a button with URL '/music/1' where artist = 1. On the 'music/1/' page, I have a button to delete a music. If possible, I want this button delete a music with url '/delmusic/1/ where music = 1 and then, returns to '/music/1/' where artist id = 1..     So, that's why I think an argument 'artist.id' is needed (to reverse view maybe ?)    But I don't know if arguments can be accepted in return redirect...  I will search about that.

Comment: yes so assuming that your music has a ForeignKey field `artist` pointing to the artist, you need to extract that before you delete the music, and then yes you can use it in `reverse` - see the edited answer

Comment: Thank you, that was I need.  Yes, I already have Foreignkey field 'artist' in my music model.    Just I will search about the correct syntax, because now, the 'reverse' search a second url with '1' (artist id).

Comment: It works :)  My music function was not named, and this is the correct syntax : `return redirect(reverse('webgui.views.music', args=[artist_id]))`     Really thank you for your help and your patience !

Comment: oh, args, right. well, I added a name for it in the edited answer